# Как в PyCharm сортировать подсказки, чтобы допустимые параметры были вверху?

Tags: pycharm

Функция может принимать аргументы. Если при её вызове при вводе параметров нажать `Ctrl+Space`, то появится меню с подсказками. Там будут и эти аргументы (со знаком `=` в конце), но не всегда в начале списка. Можно ли как то отсортировать подсказки, чтобы в самом верху были эти самые аргументы? Например отсортировать по знаку `=` в их названии.

В данном примере аргумент `a=` на второй строчке в подсказках, а аргумент `b=` где-то на 50-ой, что очень не удобно. Я же не всегда знаю какие аргументы принимает импортируемая функция, а залазить в каждую вызываемую функцию это так себе решение

[image: Скрин подсказок при вызове функции]

Comment: введите a, b тут же поднимется в первую строку :)

Comment: @splash58 во-первых нет. на первую строку поднимается только `a`. ну или точнее то, что вводилось ранее. на `b` это никак не влияет. во-вторых - эту функцию я написал. а в реальности часто импортирую функции из какого-нибудь стороннего модуля, с которым раньше не работал. я понятия не имею заранее какие там аргументы. хотелось бы сразу видеть все варианты без проваливания в саму функцию. так что это в любом случае не решение проблемы. нужна именно сортировка по типу данных из подсказки или типа того.

Answer (score 1):

Когда курсор находится в скобках нажимайте `Ctrl+P` вместо `Ctrl+Space` и не нужно будет ничего сортировать